# Gridview and Gridtile Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, gridview, widget, flutter-layout

Hi I am new to Flutter so please excuse my ignorance. I'm wondering if I can do something like this in a Gridview. **I want to make GridTile that at the top half of it is an image and the bottom part is a text**

[GridTile that I wanted to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3huC.jpg)

Because the shape of item in Gridview I can make is only square shape item. I looked into staggered grid view but I cant quite understand the coding to make the GridTile that I wanted.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

you can use childAspectRatio to do that.
For example:

```
GridView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      childAspectRatio: 9 / 10,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
    ),
    itemCount: 6,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 8),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
            ),
            Text('bla bla'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Card(
                              elevation: 10,
                              child: GridTile(
                                child: Image.network(
                                    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529220813929-597ff9755c1f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80",
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                footer: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                    height: 30,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color:
                                            Colors.grey[800].withOpacity(0.6)),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Text",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: Colors.grey[100]),
                                    )),
```